# How to make table hidden until content is filtered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i make the table below to be hidden until i search content from the search bar? i want the table to not show until the table is filtered with the search bar

```
<html>
<div class="students">
    Students

<input type="text" id="studsearch" onkeyup="StudentSearch()" placeholder="Search Student Number">
<body>
<table border ="1" cellpadding="0" id="studtable">
    <tr>
        <th>Student No.</th>    
        <th>Full Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="stud1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="stud2">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Mike</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</div>
<script>
function StudentSearch() {
  
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("studsearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("studtable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        foundHit = true;
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Im expecting the table to be hidden until searched

Answer (score 0):

Add a css style to hide the table

```
table {
  display: none;
}
```

Assuming there is a filter button/ search button

```
<input type="text" id="filter-input">
<button id="filter-button">Filter</button>
```

Add an event listener to the filter button that will show the table and filter its content when clicked,

```
//Filtering
const filterButton = document.getElementById("filter-button");
filterButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Get the filter criteria from the input field
  const filter = document.getElementById("filter-input").value;
  
  // Filter the table rows based on the criteria
  const tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    const row = tableRows[i];
    const cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    let shouldShowRow = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
      const cell = cells[j];
      if (cell.textContent.includes(filter)) {
        shouldShowRow = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldShowRow) {
      row.style.display = "";
    } else {
      row.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  
  // Show the table
  const table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  table.style.display = "";
});
```